# redirect to another page after some seconds jsf2 primefaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page that allow to edit user, and when a user click in "edit" button, I redirect him to another page for some seconds an I want to redirect him again but this time to another page once and for all, 
I tried to use `<p:poll>`

but it doesn't work
here is my code :

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template_admin.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="form">

                            <p:panel id="panel" header="Confirmation" style="width: 400px;margin: auto;" >

                                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                                    <h:outputText value="votre edition est sauvegardé avec succée"/>
                                    <h:outputText value="vous serez rediriger vers la page de la liste des utilisateurs dans quelques instants" />
                                    <p:poll interval="3" action="utilsateurs" />
                                </h:panelGrid>


                            </p:panel>

                        </h:form>

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

do you have any idea
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need poll. you can do it with plain html. add this tag to the head of the page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=otherUrl.jsf" />
```

This will redirect to "otherUrl.jsf" after 5 seconds. Since you are using a template, maybe you can add a ui:insert in the header, so you can insert the meta into the header from template client.

Comment: thank you for your response, but as you see, I work with facelet template and facelet template client, I don't have a head in this page , I have the h:head only in the facelet template

Comment: @user1581868 that's exactly why I told you to add a ui:insert in the header of the template, and in the template client, you use ui:include and put the meta tag in there

Comment: ok, you are right, I have not paid attention to this, thank you